# How to keep certain values in an array in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data array,

```
dat <- array(NA, c(115,45,248))
```

Q1: What I do if I want to get a new data array,

```
datnew <- array(NA, c(115,45,248))
```

in which, all the positive value remain and the negative value changed to `NA`?

Q2: What I do if I want to get a new data array,

```
 datnew <- array(NA,c(115,45,31))
```

by averaging with the third dimension, but only averaging every 8 values?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain Q2 a bit more? For example, using `array(rnorm(3*3*9), c(3,3,9))` going down to an array with dim `c(3,3,3)` averaging every third value, rather than your larger example. What do you mean by "every 8 values"? In my smaller example here, we have 9 3x3 matrices comprising the array. Which values do you want to average? I have two potential solutions, both different, and whether either is suitable depends on how you interpret the Q2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 2,

you can reverse the order of the dimensions, then add a dimension representing the groups to average over, then use apply:

```
tmp <- array( 1:32, c(2,2,8) )
tmp2 <- array( aperm(tmp), c(4,2,2,2) )
apply( tmp2, 2:4, mean )
```

Comment: Nice answer, Greg. Took me a little while to grep what that was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to Q1:

```
dat[dat < 0] <- NA
```

We treat `dat` as if it were a vector (it is but just with dims).

Answer to Q2:

Following Greg's nice, succinct solution, the solution I had in mind when posting my comment earlier was this (using Greg's `tmp`)

```
foo <- function(x, grp) aggregate(x, by = list(grp = grp), mean)$x
apply(tmp, 2:1, foo, grp = gl(2,4))
```

### Examples:

#### Q1

```
> dat <- array(rnorm(3*3*3), c(3,3,3))
> dat
, , 1

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.1427815  0.1642626 -0.6876034
[2,]  0.6791252  2.1420478 -0.7073936
[3,] -0.9695173 -1.1050933 -0.3068230

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.8246182  0.5132398  2.5428203
[2,] -0.4328711  0.9080648 -0.1231653
[3,] -0.7798170 -1.1160706 -0.9237559

, , 3

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.79505298  0.8795420  0.4520150
[2,]  0.04154077 -1.0422061  0.4657002
[3,] -0.67168971  0.7925304 -0.5461143

> dat[dat < 0] <- NA
> dat
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.1427815 0.1642626   NA
[2,] 0.6791252 2.1420478   NA
[3,]        NA        NA   NA

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.8246182 0.5132398 2.542820
[2,]        NA 0.9080648       NA
[3,]        NA        NA       NA

, , 3

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]         NA 0.8795420 0.4520150
[2,] 0.04154077        NA 0.4657002
[3,]         NA 0.7925304        NA
```

#### Q2

```
> foo <- function(x, grp) aggregate(x, by = list(grp = grp), mean)$x
> apply(tmp, 2:1, foo, grp = gl(2,4))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    9
[2,]   23   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8   10
[2,]   24   26
> all.equal(apply(tmp, 2:1, foo, grp = gl(2,4)), apply( tmp2, 2:4, mean ))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

```
tmp2 <- ifelse(tmp1<0,tmp1,NA)
```

For question 2 see Greg's solution.